# Set ttl for a couchbase document using Spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, couchbase

We have a big data solution built on apache spark primarily supporting data migrations between databases, i have to migrate data from db2 to couchbase using it which internaly relies on sparck-couchbase connector.
Everything works except one thing which I couldnt find a solution anywhere.
Setting ttl for the couchbase documents using spark sql.
I use sparlk sql to transform the the data into the couchbase json document structure which internally works on the DataSets.
I set document id using META_ID, so tried on the similar line as META_EXPIRATION just like it appears on the metadata block on the couchbase document.

Now that i reached the state to look for some good suggestions/help if there's really a way to achieve or the best solution is to avoid setting ttl via the connector transformation.

Appreciate any pointers?

Comment: Should the TTL be the same for all documents, or should the TTL be derived from a document field or something like that? I'm wondering if it makes sense to set a TTL on the destination collection instead of the individual documents.

Comment: @dnault - ttl is same each type of document and I need to migration 2 such types.
Is there a way in spark sql?

Comment: You can set the TTL on the bucket (or collection) in the web console.